# Chinese search form in Flash

Tags: flash, forms, cjk

I'm working on a menu with a search field, which is entirely done in Flash. On the English side works perfect; if you write "dah", it searches for "dah".  In Chinese, if you write "餅", it posts "??" instead.

I changed the encoding, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Does anybody has an idea about how I could solve the encoding issue on Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Most important: what version of Flash?
Newer versions use Unicode, so the encoding should not matter.

Just guessing from what you describe: you are using an old version of Flash (or target the result to an old player), and you are using a bad font.

The squares are actually better than question marks. It (usually) means the characters are not corrupted, but the font does not contain the glyphs needed.
Try changing the encoding to big5 and use a Traditional Chinese font (for instance MingLiU on Windows).